# My Autoit.exe doesn't work when combining with seelenium

Tags: autoit

Could you please advice me if I need to correct something?

-- Below is my script in "autoit" called "CloseWindow.exe": (converted by CloseWindow.au3 for x64)
`WinClose("Information")`
I can execute it successfully if I run this script alone

-- But when I combine it into my Selenium Script, my code of "CloseWindow.exe" doesn't work:

```
import time
import os
import autoit
import subprocess

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

vr_Chrome_Options = Options()
vr_Chrome_Options.binary_location = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ABC\\ABC_App\\ABC.exe"
        
#-- Open Aladdin Primary Port - Primary Window:
vr_Chrome_Options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
vr_Chrome_Service = Service(executable_path="C:\\Users\\dtieu\\.cache\\selenium\\chromedriver\\win64\\chromedriver_win32_version_90\\chromedriver.exe")
Driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=vr_Chrome_Service, options=vr_Chrome_Options)
time.sleep(10)
Driver.switch_to.window(Driver.window_handles[0])

vr_Connect_Device = Driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "xpathvalue...").click()
time.sleep(15)
vr_Set_Date_Time_into_SUT_Button = Driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "xpathvalue...").click()
time.sleep(10)

autoit_script_path = "D:\\PYTHON\\ABC_Testing\\CloseWindow.exe"
os.system(autoit_script_path)
```

Beside using os.system, I also try with subprocess.run
But both doesn't work.

But I can run ABC.au3 successfully. It means no problem with my script on 'ABC.au3'
Then, I convert "CloseWindow.au3" into "CloseWindow.exe"

Thanks,

Comment: By "doesn't work",  do you mean it closes immediately?  Crashes?  Outputs error?  Please explain what exactly you are trying to do.  Where does this ``CloseWindow.exe``` come in?

Comment: "doesn't work" means the message is not closed as I want.

Comment: The "CloseWindow.exe" store my code to close Window appear when working on webpage (using selenium):

Comment: "CloseWindow.exe" contains code: ``` WinClose("Information") ```

Comment: As I know nothing about AutoIT,  taking a look at https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinClose.htm,  which hWnd Window are you trying to close?  Does that window have the title "Information"?   I don't see any mention of "Information" in your post.

Comment: Yes, the window with title is "Information" and no Attributes more.
Title: Information
Class: SunAwtDisalog

Basic Control Info:    Class: <show nothing> , Instance: <show nothing>

Comment: But I am pretty sure my script in Autoit work, It can close this window.
I manual my web into this message, and my script of closing the window work fine.
Just when I combine with selenium, I cannot close the window by this script.